# sum numbers in textarea with PHP

Tags: php

I have a text area with text and some numbers, like

```
<textarea  name="text">
            Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, 1 qui's nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 55 "Duis autem" vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit 9ds88 in futurum.
</textarea>
```

How can I get a sum of all numbers in that textarea when i submit ?

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = "Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, 1 qui's nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 55 \"Duis autem\" vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit 9ds88 in futurum.";

preg_match_all('~\d+~', $str, $matches);

$sum = array_sum($matches[0]);

echo $sum;
```

To sum the data from the post - use `$_POST['text']` instead of `$str`

Comment: Very elegant, i was writing same thing, except for the "array_sum" :)

Answer (score 1):

I may be doing it a slow way, but I would:

```
$words=explode(" ",$_REQUEST['text']);
$sum=0;
foreach($words as $w){
    if(is_numeric($w)){
        $sum+=$w;
    }
}
```